# How to manage GET Method in an API

Tags: api, rest, http

I'm developing an API, reviewing documentation about HTTP Methods it says that "GET" should not modify the state of the resource. What if I want to count how many times a resource is viewed and return it on the response?

Something like

```
GET /resource/1
{
   "content": "This is the resource 1",
   "view_count": 1
}
```

In the next call it returns:

```
GET /resource/1
{
   "content": "This is the resource 1",
   "view_count": 2
}
```

Do am I violating some rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that the fact that `view_count` gets updated while using GET is not much of a violation here if you say that `view_count` is not a part of the resource itself. It is just some additional data. You could even modify your request to reflect that. Something like `GET /resource/1?include=view_count`. I think it's called resource expansion by some.

Comment: I think the same as @Viktor A. See in RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section- : "A client constructs
   request messages to communicate specific intentions". Your intention is to get the content, not modify it. So the view_count is a side effect and is not a problem. But be carefull that subsequent GET request could return a cached representation with an old "view_count". If that is a problem for you, then you should separate this value in a sub-ressource (as Viktor told you) because it will mean that it is part of the ressource and not a side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a good practice not to modify the state of a resource with a GET request, I think your use case serves as an exception. I really can't think of another way this could even be accomplished.

Edit:

Someone stated (before deleting their comment) that API users should use a `PATCH` request prior to every `GET` request to keep the `view_count` up to date.

The problem I see with this approach is that the `view_count` would become unreliable, as you're relying on your API users to keep it up to date.

Imagine if web users had to submit a request to Google Analytics everytime they visited a web page...

Comment: This is not what Google Analytics does? every page submit a request to google analytics servers?

Comment: @Pipe I meant that as a metaphor. Let me know if I can better explain it.